# Grails run-app fails with oracle-jdk-bin-1.7.0.25

Tags: hibernate, grails, jvm

My grails application does not run (throws `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [HSQL Database Engine]!` exception) after JVM upgrade to oracle-jdk-1.7.0.25. On previous version of jdk(oracle-jdk-bin-1.7.0.11) it worked fine. 
What's the problem?

Comment: i suggest you change the driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you encounter this bug:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10183

This was fixed in the latest Grails release.